# Spring boot non-fatal errors ClassNotFoundException

Tags: spring, activemq-classic, spring-boot

I'm trying to create Spring Boot application for collaboration with Apache ActiveMQ.

During startup I receiving following "non-fatal" errors:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.data.web.config.EnableSpringDataWebSupport
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_25]

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
```

This is my files:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJms
public class ActiveMQTestConfig {

    @Bean
    // Strictly speaking this bean is not necessary as boot creates a default
    JmsListenerContainerFactory<?> myJmsContainerFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        SimpleJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        return factory;
    }

}

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.example.messages")
@SpringBootApplication
public class TestConfig {    
}

@Component
public class Receiver {

    /**
     * Get a copy of the application context
     */
    @Autowired
    ConfigurableApplicationContext context;

    /**
     * When you receive a message, print it out, then shut down the application.
     * Finally, clean up any ActiveMQ server stuff.
     */
    @JmsListener(destination = "mailbox-destination", containerFactory = "myJmsContainerFactory")
    public void receiveMessage(String message) {
        System.out.println("Received <" + message + ">");
        context.close();
        FileSystemUtils.deleteRecursively(new File("activemq-data"));
    }

}

@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = { TestConfig.class, ActiveMQTestConfig.class })
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class ReceiverTest {

    @Autowired
    private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

    @Test
    public void testReceiver() {
        // Clean out any ActiveMQ data from a previous run
        FileSystemUtils.deleteRecursively(new File("activemq-data"));

        // Send a message
        MessageCreator messageCreator = new MessageCreator() {
            @Override
            public Message createMessage(Session session) throws JMSException {
                return session.createTextMessage("ping!");
            }
        };

        System.out.println("Sending a new message.");
        jmsTemplate.send("mailbox-destination", messageCreator);

    }

}
```

Logging configuration - logback.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
            <Pattern>
                %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
            </Pattern>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <logger name="org.springframework" level="debug" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </logger>

    <root level="error">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>

</configuration>
```

Dependencies configuration from parent-pom:

```
<!-- jUnit -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>${junit.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<!-- Aspectj -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
    <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
    <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
    <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Spring -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Spring boot -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
    <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
    <version>${cdi-api.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    <version>${commons-lang3.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
    <version>${commons-validator.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>${commons-io.version}</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Logging -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
    <version>${logback.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Dependencies configuration from this project:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
    <artifactId>activemq-broker</artifactId>
    <version>${activemq.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

How to prevent Spring Boot from looking for unused classes and annotations ? I don't need any web related stuff in this project.

Comment: Where do these errors come from? How have you configured logging?

Comment: Added logging configuration in the question body

Comment: What do you think this does `level="debug"`?

Comment: 2015-03-07 13:34:42 [main] DEBUG o.s.c.t.c.AnnotationAttributesReadingVisitor - Failed to class-load type while reading annotation metadata. This is a non-fatal error, but certain annotation metadata may be unavailable.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity

Comment: You have your logging set to `DEBUG` for the spring framework. Turn it  down, set it to `INFO` or `WARN`.

Comment: Please paste here your dependencies configuration

Comment: Added dependencies configuration into the question body

Comment: Spring Boot needs to detect what is on the classpath so it checks certain classes if they are there. If they are the configuration is added if not you get a debug message. This is the only way for Spring Boot to detect what is on the class path or not. To disable those messages don't log everything at debug.

Comment: Ok, I got it, thanks All for the help !

Comment: The comment-reply by @M.Deinum should be posted as an answer it seems.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Spring Boot auto configuration works by means of feature detection, much like plain Spring does at certain places (like dynamically switching between Hibernate versions).

Feature detection works by checking if some well known classes/methods/annotations of a framework, library or JDK are available. If not that feature is not available.

Spring Boot is no different, it simply checks if a class is available. In your case it is for Spring Data REST and Spring Security. For debugging Spring Boot logs those not detected features at DEBUG. This is for troubleshooting if something doesn't work you can see which part of a library you are missing.

To disable the logging simply don't log everything at DEBUG.

Answer (score 4):

Include the following depedency

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: It seems this is just including a dependency that isn't actually needed.  See the comment-reply by @M.Deinum (above, to the OP's question).

Answer (score 0):

There is explanation: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/4121
"Spring Framework uses ASM to look at the bytecode. In this case it's found an annotation that isn't on the classpath. That means that metadata about the annotation will be unavailable, nothing more. When the class is actually loaded, the JVM drops the annotation as it's not on the class path."